# Which database should I use for inhomogenous objects with large blobs and redundancy in data?

Tags: database, database-design, nosql

I am looking into storing data which I have up to now been storing in single files in a database. I am looking for some advice which database or type of database I should be using. Here is a list of requirements:

- I need to be able to store data in a hierarchical/object oriented fashion, ie have keys like car.chassis.color = red with an arbitrary depth on the keys.
- The structure of these objects is not homogeneous, some have fields that others don't.
- I would like to be able to perform queries on the keys, but i do not need the ability to do joins, ie no foreign keys necessary.
- Some of the values are large binary blobs (~several 10-100MB, never >1GB), and there is significant redundancy, so a built in compression would be good.
- Looking for an open source solution.
- I want to use it from python.

I am completely unfamiliar with anything but the most basic MySQL databases, so any pointers would be highly appreciated.

Comment: inhomogenous = heterogeneous?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a document database would fit your needs. The two I would look into are MongoDB and CouchDB (maybe also Couchbase).

Both Couch and Mongo allow for storing data as JSON, which meets your requirement for data with arbitrarily deep keys.

Both databases will also allow you to insert heterogeneous documents. Mongo specifically has an operator called $exists to check to see if a field exists in a given document.

I would give the nod to Mongo over Couch for ad-hoc querying. I just find it easier.

Neither supports joins well. It's possible with both with map/reduce functionality, but otherwise it's assumed you won't be doing joins.

Both support adding files. Mongo uses gridfs (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/gridfs/) and Couch uses attachments (http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_Document_API#Attachments).

Mongo has a Python driver (http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/python/) and Couch works via HTTP, so you only need something like curl in Python.

CouchDB is getting a lot of attention lately, but Mongo has more momentum right now.